# rails erb form helper options_for_select :selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, selected, form-helpers

I have an edit form in erb.

```
<%= form_for @animal do |f| %>
```

Within the code I have a select with options:

```
<%= f.select :gender, options_for_select([['Mare'], ['Stallion'], ['Gelding']], :selected => :gender) %>
```

However, the select is **not showing the correct selected value**.
What could I be doing wrong?
I can get it to work if I hardcode it but of course that is not a viable option.

Comment: +1 for asking a comment relating to horses, which is exactly what I'm working on as well. :)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In your code, your `options_for_select()` call sets the selected value to "gender" and does not attempt to use the value from your form object.

Please see the docs for [`options_for_select()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) for usage examples.

```
options_for_select(['Mare', 'Stallion', 'Gelding'], f.object.gender)
options_for_select(['Mare', 'Stallion', 'Gelding'], :selected => f.object.gender)
```

Alternatively, [you can do this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select), which will already use the `gender()` value for your form object:

```
<%= f.select :gender, ['Mare', 'Stallion', 'Gelding'] %>
```

Answer (score 5):

By the way, if you are using `:include_blank => true`, this will set your current selection to blank even though the form "knows" what is selected.

Comment: even though added `:include_blank => true` by this  `:selected => f.object.gender` it will work