# Rails 4: Display selected value on edit in dropdown

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, select

I have an f.select in the new article page, and it works fine. However, when I edit the article, the value changes back to whatever is first in the options.

Is there a way to keep the select value so users don't have to worry about redoing that when editing their article?

Here is my select tag:

```
<%= f.select :category, 
    options_for_select(['drink','food','medicine','supplement','drug','ingredient','lifestyle','other'], params[:category]), {}, { :class => 'span3 controls controls-row' } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `params[:category]` you should provide `selected: :category` in the `options_for_select(<...>)`.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
<%= f.select :category,   options_for_select(['drink','food','medicine','supplement','drug','ingredient','lifestyle','other'], params[:category]), {}, { :class => 'span3 controls controls-row' } %>
```

to:

```
<%= f.select :category, options_for_select(['Mare', 'Stallion', 'Gelding'], :selected => f.object.category), {}, { :class => 'span3 controls controls-row' } %>
```

which is similar to what is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19120874/3507417