# Select form helper, display existing value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this helper for my user class:

```
<%= f.select :sex, options_for_select([['Male', 0], ['Female', 1], ['Other', 2], ['Undefined', 3]]), {}, {class:"form-control"} %>
```

When I load the form, everything is filled out except the :sex value. It defaults to the first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rails erb form helper options\_for\_select :selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120706/rails-erb-form-helper-options-for-select-selected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the syntax is `select options_for_select([value1, value2, value3], default)` so in your case you can write this:

```
<%= f.select :sex, options_for_select([['Male', 0], ['Female', 1], ['Other', 2], ['Undefined', 3]], @user.sex), {}, {class:"form-control"} %>
```

assuming you have assigned @user.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<%= f.select :sex, options_for_select([['Male', 0], ['Female', 1], ['Other', 2], ['Undefined', 3]], ['Female', 1]), {}, {class:"form-control"} %>
```

the `['Female', 1]` is the default value you set; you can change it :)

the syntax is

```
select options_for_select([value1, value2, value3], default)
```

This method will respect the value that is set in the database while creating the record.