# Get Options_for_select multiple selected items to remain

Tags: html, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails form.  I know how to get an option to remain in the form when `multiple: false` (thanks to this post: [rails erb form helper options_for_select :selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120706/rails-erb-form-helper-options-for-select-selected) ) but I'm having problems when I have `multiple: true` as nothing stays highlighted when you go back to edit.

Edit Form:

```
<%= p.label :basement %>
    <%= p.select :basement, options_for_select(["Apartment", "Finished", "Partially finished", "Separate Entrance", "Unfinished", "Walk-out", "None"],selected: p.object.basement), {include_blank: false} ,{multiple: true} %>    


    <%= p.label :flooring %>
    <%= p.select :flooring, options_for_select(["Bamboo","Carpet", "Engineered Hardwood", "Hardwood", "Laminate", "Marble"],selected: p.object.flooring), {include_blank: false} ,{multiple: true} %>
```

Controller:

```
...    
def params
        params.require(:property).permit({basement:[]},{flooring:[]})
    end
```

Can anyone help me understand what I might be missing to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to use a jquery library like chosen: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ or select2: https://select2.github.io/examples.html